# .htaccess: How can I rewrite a WordPress page/section to a subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I really struggle with .htaccess. I found some possible solutions here but they give me a "Cannot find server" error. I'm using an Apache server (SiteGround).

---

I have a page (with children) set up in WordPress, and we'd like them to act as a subdomain site while still being part of our WordPress install:

```
domain.com/new
domain.com/new/children
```

I'd like these things to happen:

1. new.domain.com should load the page at domain.com/new (URL should remain new.domain.com - not redirect)
2. The children should load as new.domain.com/children
3. entering domain.com/new or domain.com/new/children should redirect to the new subdomain equivalent.

---

I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/new
RewriteRule ^new/(.*)$ http://new.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Also:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^new/$ https://new.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

They both redirect /new/ to new.domain.com/ correctly, but the subdomain itself just has a "server not found" error. I tried making an A record pointing the subdomain to the root IP address.. (I have no idea, just a stab in the dark)
Or I'm using the wrong directives?

Not opposed to using WP_Rewrite or something in functions.php if it works better, but I also have no idea about those! I normally make static marketing sites!

Comment: Just pointing the DNS to your server IP is not enough, you need to make _your_ server "know" about the subdomain as well - it needs to be able to figure out that you want requests for that subdomain to be routed into the same file system directory, as your "main" domain.

Comment: Where does `new.domain.com` point to in relation to `domain.com/new`?

Comment: Ok, I've set up a subdomain in SiteGround, pointed it to the root folder, and installed an SSL certificate there. But of course my .htaccess stuff in the root folder doesn't affect what happens in the new subfolder, so what do I need to put in the subfolder's .htaccess to hook it up?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about _configuring_ wordpress, not _development_ (see [help/on-topic]). It fits better on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Actually, the fact that it's a WordPress site is incidental. I'm asking about server configurations in Apache.